# discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int and NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

I was coding a Tax calculator system and when I'm using the function It gives me the error : `discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'`, I tried Everything but it didn't work.
Here's the function (tax calculator):

```py
async def tax(args):
  args3 = 5
  protax= round(int(args)*args3/100)
  if protax == 0:
    protax = 1
```

And here's where I called it:

```py
c.execute("SELECT price FROM netflix")
    netfprice = c.fetchall()
    netprice = netfprice[0][0]
    netprix = await tax(netprice*amount)
    embed = discord.Embed(
      title="transfer system",
      description=f"Please transfer:{netprice + netprix}"
    )
```

the full traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in command buy:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 127, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 911, in _invoke
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\sidal\Desktop\Sidtho\main.py", line 227, in buy
    description=f"Please transfer:{netprice + netprix}"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1008, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 359, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 135, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tax()` function isn't returning anything, so by default it returns None.

I suppose you want to send the `protax` variable. If that is the case, this code should work:

```py
async def tax(args):
  args3 = 5
  protax= round(int(args)*args3/100)
  if protax == 0:
    protax = 1
  return protax
```

Comment: I fell really dumb after seeing my mistake. Thank you, It worked !